# Tail probability of mean of iid R.V

Tags: probability

I have the tail probability of single R.V $Pr\{|X_i|>\varepsilon\},i=1,...,n$.
Now I want to bound the tail probability of its mean $Pr\{|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i|>\varepsilon\}$.\
I can do $Pr\{|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i|>\varepsilon\} \leq nPr\{|X_i|>\varepsilon\} $. Can I get better results? I'm anticipating the two probabilities are very close so I can remove $n$.

Comment: Consider $X_i$ being $1$ with small probability $p$, and $0 < \varepsilon < \frac1n$  Then $\Pr(|X_i|>\varepsilon) =p$ while $\Pr(|\bar X|>\varepsilon) =1-(1-p)^n = np - {n \choose 2}p^2+ {n \choose 3}p^3 -\ldots$ which may be very close to $np$ if $p$ is small enough

Comment: Thank you so much. Can it be improved if $X_i$ is continuous and has density?

Comment: Not without additional conditions: you can approximate a discrete distribution arbitrarily closely with a continuous distribution